# How can I retain a NMARoute reference after calling navigationManager.stop?

Tags: objective-c, here-api

I'm implementing the Here Maps navigation SDK in an iOS app. 
When I calculate the route before starting navigation, I save the route in an instance variable: `self.route`.

```
// Trigger the route calculation
[self.router
    calculateRouteWithStops:stops
                routingMode:routingMode
            completionBlock:^(NMARouteResult* routeResult, NMARoutingError error) {
              if (error) {
                  reject(@"route_calculation_error", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %d when calculating route", (int)error], nil);
                  return;
              }
              if (!routeResult || routeResult.routes.count == 0) {
                  reject(@"route_calculation_no_result", @"Error when calculation route: no result", nil);
                  return;
              }

              // Let's add the 1st result onto the map
              self.route = routeResult.routes[0];
              self.mapRoute = [NMAMapRoute mapRouteWithRoute:self.route];
              [self.mapView addMapObject:self.mapRoute];

              [self zoomToRoute];

              [self updateNavigationMode:kNavigationModeRoute];
              resolve(@{
                  @"length" : @(self.route.length),
                  @"duration" : @(self.route.tta.duration),
              });
            }];
```

Then when I call the function that stops navigation, the route is removed from the map and `self.route` is nil. I want to keep the route on the map and go back to itinerary view.

```
[self zoomToRoute];
[self.navigationManager stop]; // after this call, self.route == nil
[self updateNavigationMode:kNavigationModeRoute];
```

This is the solution I came up with but I'd rather not recreate the `mapRoute`, it feels hacky...

```
[self zoomToRoute];
// for some reason navigationManger#stop releases self.route and removes
// the mapRoute from the map so we create it again
NMARoute* route = self.route;
[self.navigationManager stop];
self.route = route;
self.mapRoute = [NMAMapRoute mapRouteWithRoute:self.route];
[self.mapView addMapObject:self.mapRoute];
[self updateNavigationMode:kNavigationModeRoute];
```

Answer (score 0):

NMARoute's ownership is independent of navigation and all other contexts. As long as your self.route retains a strong reference you can re-use the NMARoute object for as long as your application requires it.